# I need to split code in C for Gauss elimination method

Tags: c, split

Hello I have to split code below on 4 four files (i'm working  in visual studio). I really don't know how to do it, so I'm asking You guys for help. Thanks in advance.

Header.h (which I have)

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <conio.h>
```

main.c

data.c

solve.c

```
 #include "Header.h"

 void main(void) 
 { 
     int i,j,k,n;
     float A[20][20],c,x[10],sum=0.0;
     printf("\nEnter the order of matrix: ");
     scanf("%d",&n);
     printf("\nEnter the elements of augmented matrix row-wise:\n\n");
     for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
     {
        for(j=1; j<=(n+1); j++)
        {
            printf("A[%d][%d] : ", i,j);
            scanf("%f",&A[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(j=1; j<=n; j++) 
    {
        for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            if(i>j)
            {
                c=A[i][j]/A[j][j];
                for(k=1; k<=n+1; k++)
                {
                    A[i][k]=A[i][k]-c*A[j][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    x[n]=A[n][n+1]/A[n][n];
    for(i=n-1; i>=1; i--)
    {
        sum=0;
        for(j=i+1; j<=n; j++)
        {
            sum=sum+A[i][j]*x[j];
        }
        x[i]=(A[i][n+1]-sum)/A[i][i];
    }
    printf("\nThe solution is: \n");
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        printf("\nx%d=%f\t",i,x[i]); 
    }
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: I've done Header.h which looks like

    #include<iostream>
    #include<conio.h>

And I also know, that I need to contain 

     #include "Header.h" in every file I make (I mean every except Header.h)

I also think something is missing in Header

Comment: `#include <iostream>` O_o are you sure you're using `C` ?

Comment: Please respect ancient scientists, Gauss not gausse...

Comment: @George sorry I meant 

#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

Comment: @Matitiitit97 you claim you have `Header.h`, so why don't you show it in the question? It's relevant.

Comment: @MichaelWalz There You go

Comment: You need to do 2 distinct things: first of all you need to split your program into different _functions_, probably one function that lets you enter a matrix, one that displays a matrix and one that solves the matrix. Once this has been done, you need put the functions in different files.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Okay can You help me do just one? There I'll know how to do rest. Let's say maybe function that solve the matrix? Thank You for Your time before and now.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a start. Here the `Solve` function contains the solving part. Proceed similarly with the other function to be written by you such as `MatrixInput`, `MatrixOutput`.

You probably should read the part dealing with functions in your C textbook.
Disclaimer: this is untested code and there is still room for improvement.

```
#include <stdio.h>    

void Solve(int n, float A[20][20], float x[20])
{
  float sum = 0.0;
  int i, j, k;
  float c;
  for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
  {
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
      if (i > j)
      {
        c = A[i][j] / A[j][j];
        for (k = 1; k <= n + 1; k++)
        {
          A[i][k] = A[i][k] - c*A[j][k];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  x[n] = A[n][n + 1] / A[n][n];
  for (i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--)
  {
    sum = 0;
    for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
      sum = sum + A[i][j] * x[j];
    }
    x[i] = (A[i][n + 1] - sum) / A[i][i];
  }
}


int main()
{
  int i, j, n;
  float A[20][20],x[20];
  printf("\nEnter the order of matrix: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("\nEnter the elements of augmented matrix row-wise:\n\n");

  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  {
    for (j = 1; j <= (n + 1); j++)
    {
      printf("A[%d][%d] : ", i, j);
      scanf("%f", &A[i][j]);
    }
  }

  Solve(n, A, x);

  printf("\nThe solution is: \n");
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  {
    printf("\nx%d=%f\t", i, x[i]);
  }
  _getch();
}
```

Comment: Thank You! Im so glad that You help me with this. Now I know what to do next.

Comment: @Matitiitit97 feel free to upvote and/or to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize but I'm working with gcc compiler in Linux OS so I don't have VS and I can't use some of you libraries (conio.h ... ) but these fragments of code should give you the general idea.

header.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getData(float A[20][20], int n);
void degauss(float A[20][20], float x[10], int n);
```

main.c:

```
#include "header.h"

void main(void)
{
        int i, n;
        float A[20][20],c,x[10],sum=0.0;
        printf("\nEnter the order of matrix: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);

        getData(A, n);
        degauss(A, x, n);

        printf("\nThe solution is: \n");
        for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
                printf("\nx%d=%f\t",i,x[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");

//      getch_();
}
```

data.c:

```
include "header.h"

void getData(float A[20][20], int n)
{
        int i, j;
        printf("\nEnter the elements of augmented matrix row-wise:\n\n");
        for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
                for(j=1; j<=(n+1); j++)
                {
                        printf("A[%d][%d] : ", i,j);
                        scanf("%f",&A[i][j]);
                }
        }
}
```

solve.c:

```
#include "header.h"

void degauss(float A[20][20], float x[10], int n)
{
        float c, sum=0.0;
        int i, j, k;
        for(j=1; j<=n; j++) 
        {
                for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
                {
                        if(i>j)
                        {
                                c=A[i][j]/A[j][j];
                                for(k=1; k<=n+1; k++)
                                {
                                        A[i][k]=A[i][k]-c*A[j][k];
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
        x[n]=A[n][n+1]/A[n][n];
        for(i=n-1; i>=1; i--)
        {
                sum=0;
                for(j=i+1; j<=n; j++)
                {
                        sum=sum+A[i][j]*x[j];
                }
                x[i]=(A[i][n+1]-sum)/A[i][i];
        }
}
```

This is just a starting point, You can, for example, use an header file for each source file, and You can move the portion of code that takes the matrix order from standard input on the data.c source file.